# About Spring aspectj load time weaving execution order

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

```
@Configurable(preConstruction = false)
public class Mock implements IMock
{

    @Autowired
    private Foo foo;


    public Mock()
    {
        System.out.println("i need foo in the constructor but it is not autowired at this point " + foo);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void start()
    {
        System.out.println("starting");
    }
}
```

When I set up Spring Aspectj load time weaving and created a instance through `new` keyword like this(below). It turns out that I have no access to the dependencies in the constructor. That's all fine as expected. The execution order was `constructor->autowire->postconstruct` .

```
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        URL url = Main.class.getResource("applicationContext.xml");
        FileSystemXmlApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(url.getPath());

        Mock mock = new Mock();
    }
}
```

So I set `@Configurable(preConstruction = true)`. Now I can access the dependencies in the constructor. But the problem is the execution order: `autowire->postconstruct->construct` .  Why postconstruct comes before construct? That's not what I expected.

Did I misunderstand something? What is the semantics of @PostConstruct? Is it "post constructor" or "post dependency injection"? I checked out the javadoc of @PostConstruct. It says nothing about constructor.

**EDIT:** btw, here are the libraries versions I use:

spring-aspects 4.1.6.RELEASE

spring-instrument 4.1.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@PostConstruct` is handled in Spring by the `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` and is run together with all bean configuration post-processors that are configured for the given bean factory and applicable to the bean in question (in the order they are configured to run). The `@Configurable` annotation just marks otherwise not Spring managed beans to be eligible for autowiring and bean post-processing by Spring, and it's done through `AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect`. `preConstruction=true` will signal that this configuration should happen before the constructor of the object in question is run. That means that if `preConstruction=true`, by the time the constructor of the object in question is being run, Spring will have finished its configuration of the object.

TL;DR - yes, this is the intended order things should happen in your case.